# Multidimensional array association

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, routesFeatures and stopsFeatures, they contain attributes for a vehicle route and attributes for every stop, respectively. They are associated with one another via their name attributes, meaning if the **RouteName** attribute in any of the entries in **stopsFeatures** matches with the **Name** attribute in any entry of **routesFeatures** it means the stop point belongs to that route.
Now code-wise I'm trying to this matching and place them in a bidimensional array where every index is a route and inside that index theres the corresponding stops.

This is routesFeatures:

```js
[{
    ObjectId: 1,
    Name: "Rota 1"
  },
  {
    ObjectId: 2,
    Name: "Rota 2"
  },
  ...
]
```

This is stopsFeatures:

```js
[{
    ObjectId: 1,
    Name: "Carga 0",
    RouteName: "Rota 2"
  },
  {
    ObjectId: 2,
    Name: "Descarga 0",
    RouteName: "Rota 2"
  },
  ...,
  {
    ObjectId: 11,
    Name: "Carga 5",
    RouteName: "Rota 4"
  },
  ...
]
```

This is my function:

```
function drawRoutesOptimized(routesFeatures, stopsFeatures){
    var stopsRoutes = [[]];
    for(var i=0; i<routesFeatures.length; i++){
        // draw some stuff on screen
        var count = 0;
        for(var j=0; j<stopsFeatures.length; j++){
            if(stopsFeatures[j].attributes.RouteName == routesFeatures[i].attributes.Name){
                stopsRoutes[i][count] = stopsFeatures[j].attributes.Name;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a console.log for stopsRoutes which is working as intented but only when the i is 0 then it crashes:

```
[0]
    [0] "Carga 2"
    [1] "Descarga 2"
    [2] "Carga 6"
    [3] "Descarga 6"
    [4] "Carga 7"
    [5] "Descarga 7"
```

In my head this should work but I'm getting:
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined**
when the i becomes the value 1

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like the data to look like? Preferably in JSON format.

Comment: I will update my question with an example but this is what I want and get with my function but it only runs when the i is 0, it crashes and gives the error in the question when i gets incremented. https://prnt.sc/vdxoeg

Comment: Do you care if there are duplicates in the list? e.g. can "Carga 2" appear twice in the list?

Comment: Duplicates are fine

Comment: I think is related to the need to reserve space for `stopRoutes` before writing into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically it's pretty straight forward.

1. Loop through the routes
2. Per Route, Loop through Stops
3. Add Stops who's `RouteName` matches the Route

This is not the most optimized solution, but it works. Bear in mind that I'm using [reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) to initialize each route as an array.

```js
const routesFeatures = [{
    ObjectId: 1,
    Name: "Rota 1"
  },
  {
    ObjectId: 2,
    Name: "Rota 2"
  },
];
const stopFeatures = [{
    ObjectId: 1,
    Name: "Carga 0",
    RouteName: "Rota 2"
  },
  {
    ObjectId: 2,
    Name: "Descarga 0",
    RouteName: "Rota 2"
  },
  {
    ObjectId: 11,
    Name: "Carga 5",
    RouteName: "Rota 4"
  },
];
const result = routesFeatures.reduce((acc, routeFeature) => {
  acc.push(stopFeatures.reduce((_acc, stopFeature) => {
    if (stopFeature.RouteName === routeFeature.Name) {
      _acc.push(stopFeature.RouteName)
    }
    return _acc;
  }, []))
  return acc
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Using a standard for-loop

```js
const routesFeatures = [{
    ObjectId: 1,
    Name: "Rota 1"
  },
  {
    ObjectId: 2,
    Name: "Rota 2"
  },
];
const stopsFeatures = [{
    ObjectId: 1,
    Name: "Carga 0",
    RouteName: "Rota 2"
  },
  {
    ObjectId: 2,
    Name: "Descarga 0",
    RouteName: "Rota 2"
  },
  {
    ObjectId: 11,
    Name: "Carga 5",
    RouteName: "Rota 4"
  },
];

function drawRoutesOptimized(routesFeatures, stopsFeatures) {
  const routeStops = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < routesFeatures.length; i++) {
    routeStops.push([]);
    const routeArray = routeStops[i];
    const route = routesFeatures[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < stopsFeatures.length; j++) {
      const stop = stopsFeatures[j];
      if (stop.RouteName === route.Name) {
        routeArray.push(stop.RouteName)
      }
    }
  }
  return routeStops
}
const result = drawRoutesOptimized(routesFeatures, stopsFeatures);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This worked great. Many thanks, I will be looking into reduce() to do these sort of matches into different arrays in the future instead of how I was doing things.

Comment: Went ahead and added a for-loop as well

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you want actually, and I remove the attributes param to make it this works in snippets. You miss declaring the sub array so when routes have no way to push data into the array.

```js
let routesFeatures = [{
    ObjectId: 1,
    Name: "Rota 1"
  },
  {
    ObjectId: 2,
    Name: "Rota 2"
  }
]


let stopsFeatures = [{
    ObjectId: 1,
    Name: "Carga 0",
    RouteName: "Rota 2"
  },
  {
    ObjectId: 2,
    Name: "Descarga 0",
    RouteName: "Rota 2"
  }
]

function drawRoutesOptimized(routesFeatures, stopsFeatures){
    var stopsRoutes = [];
    for(var i=0; i<routesFeatures.length; i++){
        // draw some stuff on screen
        var count = 0;
        stopsRoutes[i] = [];
        for(var j=0; j<stopsFeatures.length; j++){
            if(stopsFeatures[j].RouteName == routesFeatures[i].Name){
                stopsRoutes[i][count] = stopsFeatures[j].Name;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(stopsRoutes)
}

drawRoutesOptimized(routesFeatures, stopsFeatures)
```

Comment: I see, all I was missing initially was stopsRoutes[i] = []; Thank you.